New tag to represent value added services (on top of Bitcoin)
I think it would be benefical to tag services (current or future/proposed) layers of the Bitcoin network accordingly.
One example is this question where I ask about a P2P anonymous rating system.  This relates to Bitcoin in technology, but is layered above the base protocol/technology.
Thoughts? 

The only name for such services I could think of currently is "Bitcoin Ecosystem", a term I started using in my master thesis. However, I don't think such a general tag would be too beneficial, whatever it would be. Trying to establish a convention top-down might not work too well if there isn't any work going from bottom-up. So I would argue to just let everyone tag their question how they please, and if we see some tag emerging and being useful, we could try incorporating more question to it.
